# Autocomplete Drop down box selenium webdriver

Tags: selenium, webdriver, dropdown

I need to select the address from the auto complete drop down in selenium webdriver.

I have added the inspect element source of the drop down box as follows,

```
<div id="wrapper">
<ul id="ui-id-1" class="ui-autocomplete ui-front ui-menu ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" tabindex="0" style="display: none;"/>
<div class="k-widget k-window" style="padding-top: 33px; min-width: 90px; min-height: 50px; width: 200px; display: none; top: 600px; left: 5px;" data-role="draggable">
<div class="k-widget k-window" style="padding-top: 33px; min-width: 90px; min-height: 50px; width: 200px; display: none; top: 600px; left: 5px;" data-role="draggable">
<div class="k-widget k-window" style="padding-top: 33px; min-width: 90px; min-height: 50px; width: 200px; display: none; top: 600px; left: 5px;" data-role="draggable">
<div class="datepicker datepicker-dropdown dropdown-menu" style="display: none;">
<div class="datepicker datepicker-dropdown dropdown-menu" style="display: none;">
<div class="datepicker datepicker-dropdown dropdown-menu" style="display: none;">
<div class="datepicker datepicker-dropdown dropdown-menu" style="display: none;">
<div class="datepicker datepicker-dropdown dropdown-menu" style="display: none;">
<div class="datepicker datepicker-dropdown dropdown-menu" style="display: none;">
<ul id="ui-id-2" class="ui-autocomplete ui-front ui-menu ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" tabindex="0" style="display: none;"/>
<ul id="ui-id-3" class="ui-autocomplete ui-front ui-menu ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" tabindex="0" style="display: none; width: 540px; top: 694.783px; left: 510px;">
<li class="ui-menu-item" role="presentation">
<a id="ui-id-704" class="ui-corner-all" tabindex="-1">SYDNEY, New South Wales, Australia, 1001</a>
</li>
<li class="ui-menu-item" role="presentation">
<a id="ui-id-705" class="ui-corner-all" tabindex="-1">SYDNEY, New South Wales, Australia, 1002</a>
</li>
<li class="ui-menu-item" role="presentation">
<a id="ui-id-706" class="ui-corner-all" tabindex="-1">SYDNEY, New South Wales, Australia, 1003</a>
</li>
<li class="ui-menu-item" role="presentation">
<a id="ui-id-707" class="ui-corner-all" tabindex="-1">SYDNEY, New South Wales, Australia, 1005</a>
</li>
<li class="ui-menu-item" role="presentation">
<li class="ui-menu-item" role="presentation">
```

I need to select the "SYDNEY, New South Wales, Australia, 1001" drop down value from the autocomplete box. Please suggest me some idea. I have used the following code but it is not working,

```
driver.findElement(By.id("HomeAddress_AddressLine1")).sendKeys("Walker Street");
        driver.findElement(By.id("HomeAddress_City")).click();
        driver.findElement(By.id("HomeAddress_City")).sendKeys("sydney");
        Thread.sleep(3000);
        WebElement select = driver.findElement(By.id("ui-id-3"));

        java.util.List<WebElement> options = select.findElements(By.tagName("li"));

        for (WebElement option1 : options) {

        if("SYDNEY, New South Wales, Australia, 1001".equals(option1.getText().trim()))

         option1.click();   
        }       
        Thread.sleep(2000);
```

Please suggest me how to get that values. The problem here is the id value ui-id-3 is changing every time when the page is reloading i.e (like ui-id-12, ui-id-18). I have attached the screen shots of the page along with this.

Thank you.[image]

Comment: Select class will not work here because there is no select class present in DOM. You have to use either xpath or CSS to make it work

Answer (score 0):

You need to click the "dropdown" to open it and display the city options then click on the desired city. Each of the city names are in an A tag so you can use `By.linkText()` to find them. I wrapped this in a function to make it reusable.

```
public static void setCity(String cityName)
{
    driver.findElement(By.id("ui-id-3")).click(); // click the "dropdown" to display the list of options
    driver.findElement(By.linkText(cityName)).click();
}
```

... and you call it like

```
setCity("SYDNEY, New South Wales, Australia, 1001");
```